# Unlabeled Statement in java

Tags: java, continue

I need some help to understand what the Unlabeled Statement. 
I have a example:

```
for(int var1 =0; var1 < 5 ; var1++) {
    for(int var2=0 ; var2 < 5 ; var2++){
        if(var2 == 2)
            continue;
            System.out.println("var1:" + var1 + "  var2:"+ var2);
    }
}
```

but when i executed it's not skips the current iteration of innermost for loop, a have the following output:

```
 var1:0 var2:0 
 var1:0 var2:1 
 var1:0 var2:3 
 var1:0 var2:4 
 var1:1 var2:0 
 var1:1 var2:1 
 var1:1 var2:3 
 var1:1 var2:4 
 var1:2 var2:0 
 var1:2 var2:1 
 var1:2 var2:3 
 var1:2 var2:4 
 var1:3 var2:0 
 var1:3 var2:1 
 var1:3 var2:3 
 var1:3 var2:4 
 var1:4 var2:0 
 var1:4 var2:1 
 var1:4 var2:3 
 var1:4 var2:4
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. The iteration of the inner loop when `var2` is `2` is skipped, as shown by the output. What is the issue?

Comment: I tested this example from this site http://www.java-examples.com/continue-statement but after this description "This form of statement causes skips the current iteration of innermost for" the code not skips innermost for loop

Comment: If you don't use continue; then var2:2 also got printed that means continue; skips executing of System.out.println

Answer (score 0):

You `continue` statement does skip a single iteration of the inner loop :

```
var1:2 var2:1 var1:2 var2:3
```

You can see that var2:2 is skipped.

If you wish to skip what remains of the current execution of the inner loop, use `break` instead of `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

It **does** skip the current iteration of the inner for loop.

You can see it from the output:

```
var1:0 var2:1 var1:0 var2:3
```

--> `var2 == 2` is skipped.

Note that your `continue` statement is in scope with the `var2 == 2` check only: your bad indenting suggests somehow that the `println` statement would follow `continue`, which may seem misleading.

Answer (score 0):

`continue` statement does skip a single iteration of the inner loop

as you see in your output `var2:2` is always skipped

`continue`: update expression of the innermost for loop. It is used to early-terminate a loop's processing.

From [javaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) : The continue statement skips the current iteration of a for, while , or do-while loop. The unlabeled form skips to the end of the innermost loop's body and evaluates the boolean expression that controls the loop.

Comment: In this case the Unlabeled continue Statemen, is to skip some iteration of loop according to condition of if statement?